# Object not found error after rewrite the URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have two types of URL on my website which are

First URL set

```
<a href="services_name1">Service name1</a>
```

Second URL set

```
<a href="journel.php?name=services_name1">Service name1</a>
```

Now what I am doing is, For the first URL, I want URL like

```
services/services_name1
```

So I used like below code in htaccess and it's working

```
RewriteRule ^services/services_name1$ services_name1
```

My issue is with the second URL.
For the second URL, I want my URL like

```
services/authors/services_name1
```

I tried below code in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/?services/authors/([0-9]+)$ /journel.php?name=$1
```

but it not working. I am getting 404.

I am using  `<a href="services/authors/services_name1">click here</a>`

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^home$ index
RewriteRule ^about-us$ aboutus
RewriteRule ^services/authors$ authors


RewriteRule ^/?services/authors/([0-9\w]+)$ /journel.php?name=$1

FileETag MTime Size
</IfModule>
```

Would you help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?services/authors/([0-9]+)$ /journel.php?name=$1
```

only matches numbers(because of the `0-9`) after `/authors/` such as `/authors/22/`. To allow characters(words/dashes) `\w`  can be used:

```
RewriteRule ^/?services/authors/([0-9\w]+)$ /journel.php?name=$1
```

Updated order with entire .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^home$ index
RewriteRule ^about-us$ aboutus
RewriteRule ^services/authors$ authors
RewriteRule ^/?services/authors/([0-9\w]+)$ /journel.php?name=$1

FileETag MTime Size
</IfModule>
```

Checkout the regex cheatsheet:  https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: Still, I am getting 404. I added   <a href="services/authors/services_name1"> and your answer in htaccess code.

Comment: could you try using `/services/authors/services_name1`? If this doesn't work, could you share your `.htaccess` file? @questionbank

Comment: I added in the question.

Comment: Checkout the updated example @questionbank

Comment: I am getting an internal server error. home, about-us and service links are not working. Because I added the REQUEST_FILENAME code at the bottom. I think I can't use it at bottom

Comment: Ok updated the answer. Is this .htaccess located in a subdirectory or the root of the domain? Is it like: `http://example.com/services/authors/services_name1`? @questionbank

Comment: Yes, I want http://example.com/services/authors/services_name1 URL instated of <a href="journel.php?name=services_name1">Service name1</a>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198762/discussion-between-maartendev-and-questionbank).

Comment: Checkout the updated chat @questionbank