# htaccess RewriteRule results in "Object not found!"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My actual URL is  `<a href="<?php echo siteUrl;?>view.php?name=<?php echo $slug_url?>"><?php echo $heroheading ?></a>`

Output

```
<a href="http://example.com/view.php?name=search-result">Click me</a>
```

What I am doing is, I have to rewrite the URL. I want to display the URL like

http://example.com/admin/service/search-result

and I added in the HTML `<a href="<?php echo siteUrl;?>admin/service/<?php echo $slug_url?>"><?php echo $heroheading ?></a>`

I tried below code in .htaccess but I am getting "Object not found!"

```
RewriteRule ^/?admin/service/([0-9\w]+)$ /view.php?name=$1
```

I checked on google and I tried same code but don't know why it's not working.

Would you help me out?

Comment: It's always /admin/service?

Comment: @MosesSchwartz, Yes

Comment: I would recommend using a router instead. Then the "nice ulr's" are a part of your application instead of the web server config. Specially if you want your application to run on more servers than Apache without the need to create all those rules again in another format for another web server,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Just change your rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?admin/service/([\w-]+)/?$ view.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

`\w` is equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9-]` so `0-9` is not required separately. Also you will need `-` in character class to match `-` in `search-result`.

Comment: Give me some time to check

Comment: It's still showing Object not found  https://prnt.sc/p1o39v  and my URL is http://localhost:8080/test-w/admin/service/blog

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located and where is `view.php` located?

Comment: Yes, It's working. @anubhava, Thanks for the help. I was trying to solve this issue from last 4 days and you solved it within 2 mins.

Comment: I asked one question here: You can also add your answer or mark as duplicate.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57736704/object-not-found-error-after-rewrite-the-url

Comment: Sure, I will take a look.